# Handling javascript popup in watir

Tags: ruby, watir, autoit, javascript

I am using autoit to handle javas script popup code as

```
autoit.WinWaitActive("[Class:#32770]")

result =autoit.ControlClick("[Class:#32770]","","Button1")
```

But when I click on the button to open the popup it waits for a longer time & if the user is performing operations on another window, it will no go further. Only when the user clicks on the current window does it work. Means user should be focused on IE browser at the time of javascript popup.

Comment: You might consider moving to Watir 2.0.x and using RAutomation instead of AutoIt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most tools that work up at the OS UI level (as autoit does) require that the window to be worked on has focus in order to have things like clicks or keyboard input end up in the correct window.

You'll probably want to set the focus first, then try to click, if you are using autoit

There are other methods for dealing with JS popups, especially with more current versions (1.9.0 or above) of watir, which are more elegant.  Refer to the [Javascript Popups page](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/JavaScript+Pop+Ups) in the Watir Wiki

Do be aware that most of the solutions you see presume that the browser will have focus.  If you need to run scripts at the same time as doing other work and don't want what you are doing to interfere, I might recommend using a virtual machine to run the scripts

Comment: & autoit taking to much time to open javascript window & run script ? anyone has idea why so much time it take to open that popup?